# LWJGL - display lists not working

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, displaylist

I want to render some meshes in LWJGL.
When I use the default way to render the objects (glVertex3f etc.), there are no problems.
But when I want to render the objects using display lists, the screen is emty.
I use the same code for initializing the display list, which I'm using for the default rendering.

```
glViewport(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45.0f, getHeight() / getHeight(), 1.0f, 1000.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glLoadIdentity();
//...
this.displayList = glGenLists(1);
//...
glNewList(displayList, GL_COMPILE);
//[same code I use for the default rendering way]
GL11.glEndList();
//...
glCallList(displayList);
```

I have no idea,why this doesn't work

Is there anything I should take care of when working with display lists ?

Comment: I assume you called `glEndList()` somewhere in that `...`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be missing a call to `glEndList()`. You need to call that after you finished rendering everything you want in the display list, and before calling `glCallList()`.

Comment: Oh sorry,that was a writing error. I meant GL11.glEndList(); instead of GL11.glEnd(); But thanks for helping anyway !

Comment: Ah, ok, it's not that easy then. What kind of rendering commands are you using? See https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glNewList.xml for a list of calls that are not supported inside display lists. And I know this is not an answer, but since this is now I comment I'll say it anyway: Just say no to display lists. They have been obsolete for at least 15 years.